# Ask word that contains a letters contained in a array

Tags: java, arrays

I have a problem. I want my program ask me that I insert a word, and the letters of this word must be contained in an array.

for the time being, I want if the letters are contained in the array, print ("The letter is correct"), else print("The letter is incorrect").

But always return ("The letter is incorrect"), WHY?

HELP ME PLEASE!

public class Utils {

```
Scanner ent = new Scanner(System.in);
String insertedLetter = "";
String letters[] = {"a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "i", "j", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "r"};
String saveLetter = "";

public void askLetter() {
    for (int i = 0; i < letters.length; i++) {
        saveLetter += " " + letters[i] + ",";
    }
    System.out.println("Insert a word that contains these letters " + saveLetter);
    insertedLetter = ent.nextLine();

    if (saveLetter.equals(insertedLetter)) {
        System.out.println("The letter is correct");
    } else {
        System.out.println("The letter is incorrect");
    }
}
```

}

Comment: What do you think the `equals` method does? Your program will only output correct if the input is `" a, b, c, d, e, f, g, i, j, l, m, n, o, p, r,"`. I'm not sure this is what you are looking for.

Comment: There is one, and only one, input that will match your `saveLetter` - that is

    Insert a word that contains these letters  a, b, c, d, e, f, g, i, j, l, m, n, o, p, r,
     a, b, c, d, e, f, g, i, j, l, m, n, o, p, r,
    The letter is correct

" a, b, c, d, e, f, g, i, j, l, m, n, o, p, r,"... you need to try a "contains" method.

Comment: Is `insertedLetter.matches( "[a-r]+" )` doing what you what? Not sure if you accept empty string - that would be done in a separate check.

Comment: I want that I insert "f", return "The word is correct", because the  letters "f" is contained in the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple way of doing this would be something like the following:

```
    boolean contained = true;
    for (int i = 0; i < insertedLetter.length(); i++) {
        if (saveLetter.indexOf(insertedLetter.charAt(i)) == -1) {
            contained = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (contained) {
        System.out.println("The letters are all contained in the saveLetter array");
    } else {
        System.out.println("One or more of the input letters are not contained in the saveLetter array");
    }
```

Comment: I got the impression that he wanted to print letter by letter, your code can easily be adapted to this though.

Comment: Oh! thank you very much! is this that I want! Thank you so much!